# Create a channel with a reaction - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I would like that when a member clicks on a certain reaction, the bot create a channel but it doesn't work :

My code :

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    reaction = (u"\U0001F4E9")
    if reaction == reaction :
        channel = await payload.create_text_channel('Tickets', overwrites=None, reason=None)
        return channel
```

The Error :

```
AttributeError: 'RawReactionActionEvent' object has no attribute 'create_text_channel'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can by getting the guild from `guild_id`

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if str(payload.emoji) == "":
        guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        channel = await guil.create_text_channel('Tickets')
        return channel
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it's probably not needed to use a `raw_reaction_add`, instead you can just use a `on_reaction_add` event which would always wait for a user to react with your specified emoji

However, it's not like you can just pass ctx, so you have to use `reaction` as your argument, then the message channel. You can define the guild simply with `reaction.message.guild`.

Here's a simple example of using this, make sure to add other changes or checks eg. Checking if the reaction was in a specified guild or message id.

```py
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
        if reaction.emoji == '':
            guild = reaction.message.guild
            await guild.create_text_channel('Tickets', overwrites=None, reason=None)
            await reaction.message.channel.send('Created a ticket!')
```

The error in your code is also explanatory, `AttributeError: 'RawReactionActionEvent' object has no attribute 'create_text_channel` simply means `payload` hasn't got an attribute for `create_text_channel`, however including `message` would allow this. Raw reaction add isn't needed in this case